# sshd Match directive

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I encountered an issue on the way the sshd daemon is configured, here we have a couple of path exposed in RO by a server, the end user have to use the service in RO on their machine use sshfs to mount it.

The configuration are:

```
Match Group ADGroup1
  # Force the connection to use SFTP and chroot to the required directory.
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  ChrootDirectory /ADGroup1Dir
  # Disable tunneling, authentication agent, TCP and X11 forwarding.
  PermitTunnel no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no

Match Group ADGroup2
  # Force the connection to use SFTP and chroot to the required directory.
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  ChrootDirectory /ADGroup2Dir
  # Disable tunneling, authentication agent, TCP and X11 forwarding.
  PermitTunnel no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

Usually every think works, except when some user are present in both group.
Ssh chrootdirectory the user on the first match and the mount works only with the following command:

```
sshfs aduser@server:/ /localpath
```

whit the following command we receive a no such file or directory error:

```
sshfs aduser@server:/ADGroup2Dir
```

but by watching the debug log of ssh server, the only No such file or directory error are saying that the `/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server` are not found.

Some body can help to figured out this issue?

Comment: do you have in `sshd` config line like: `Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server`? Did you check if the file exist? And do you have `selinux` activated?

Comment: yes, the Subsystem is declared in to the configuration files and selinux is disabled